# Why the inconsistency of file content occurred after downloading LOB in SequoiaDB?

Tags: database, sequoiadb

When I use python to create LOB in SequoiaDB, and then download LOB, I find that the content of LOB is inconsistent with the original file.

Answer (score 0):

1.Users use Python driver to create LOB, as the following example:
obj = cl_model.create_lob()
obj.write( content, len( content ) )

2.Users do not close the input stream, resulting in the content inconsistency when reading LOB. Close the LOB input stream example:
obj.close()

3.There are python driver basic operation examples in the installation directory of SequoiaDB.
path: /sequoiadb/samples/Python/sequoiadb/